# How to rewrite this Curl call (to the Apache Hue REST API) as (JQuery) AJAX?

Tags: jquery, curl, hue

I need to call the Apache Hue REST API via AJAX calls (using JQuery for example) and so I need to convert the following curl call to AJAX (taken from https://docs.gethue.com/developer/api/#execute-a-query )

```
curl -X POST https://demo.gethue.com/notebook/api/execute/hive --data 'executable={"statement":"SHOW TABLES","database":"default"}&notebook={"type":"query","snippets":[{"id":1,"statement_raw":"SHOW TABLES","type":"hive","variables":[]}],"name":"","isSaved":false,"sessions":[]}&snippet={"id":1,"type":"hive","result":{},"statement":"SHOW TABLES","properties":{}}'
```

(obviously I'm using the URL of my Hue installation and my query would be something like "SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10;")

This was one of my attempts, but I always get back an error in the console `{status: -1, message: "'type'"}`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/notebook/api/execute/hive/",
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    data: {"executable": JSON.stringify({"statement":"SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10","database":"default"}), "notebook": JSON.stringify({"type":"query","snippets":[{"id":1,"statement_raw":"SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10","type":"hive","variables":[]}],"name":"","isSaved":false,"sessions":[]}), "snippet": JSON.stringify({"id":1,"type":"hive","result":{},"statement":"SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10","properties":{}})},
    success: function(data) { console.log(data); },
    error: function(err) { console.log(err); }
});
```

However I tried the following in Chrome devtools console (I am logged into Hue via the web interface on the same page as the console) and it works fine, so I know the above should work if I can get the syntax right:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/notebook/api/autocomplete/",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"snippet": JSON.stringify({"type": "hive"})},
    success: function(data) {console.log(data); }
});
```

For reference, the curl equivalent of that is here (although it seems I don't need to specify CRSF or sessionID because I'm already logged in via the interface in the same browser window as the console):

```
curl -X POST https://demo.gethue.com/notebook/api/autocomplete/ --data 'snippet={"type":"hive"}' --cookie "csrftoken=XUFgN1WPZNlaJtBeBDtBvwzrOFqRXIaMlNJv4mdvsS2bIE2Lb8LRmCh5cPUBnBdk;sessionid=9cdltfee1q1zmt8b7slsjcomtxzgvgfz" -H "X-CSRFToken: XUFgN1WPZNlaJtBeBDtBvwzrOFqRXIaMlNJv4mdvsS2bIE2Lb8LRmCh5cPUBnBdk
```

Any suggestions very welcome!
Thanks

Comment: Remove `processData`, or set it to its default `true` value

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks good suggestion, but after doing that I get back: {status: -1, message: "'handle'"} so something else is going on...